# MY Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, min

```
SELECT  C.ID
 ,C.Name
 ,C.Email
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT SE.ID) 'Servers'
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT SI.ID) 'Sites'
 ,Coalesce(SUM( DISTINCT SU.Users),0 ) 'User'

//this part I am doing wrong, how can i get the enddate of 2 tables
 ,***(SELECT MIN(EndDate) 'EndDate'
   FROM
   (SELECT SLD.EndDate AS EndDate 
     UNION 
       SELECT SILD.EndDate AS EndDate ) AS EndDate )***


FROM Customer AS C
LEFT JOIN ServerLicenseDetails AS SLD ON C.ID = SLD.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Server AS SE ON SLD.ServerID = SE.ID
LEFT JOIN Site AS SI ON SE.ID = SI.ServerID 
LEFT JOIN SiteUsers AS SU ON SI.ID = SU.SiteID
LEFT JOIN SiteLicenseDetails AS SILD ON SI.ID = SILD.ID

GROUP BY C.ID
,C.Name
,C.Email
```

How to fix it because I want to get the minimal enddate compare with 2 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CASE WHEN` Clause as follows :

```
SELECT  C.ID
 ,C.Name
 ,C.Email
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT SE.ID) 'Servers'
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT SI.ID) 'Sites'
 ,Coalesce(SUM( DISTINCT SU.Users),0 ) 'User'
 ,CASE WHEN min(SLD.EndDate) > min(SILD.EndDate) then min(SILD.EndDate) else min(SLD.EndDate) end as 'EndDate'
FROM Customer AS C
LEFT JOIN ServerLicenseDetails AS SLD ON C.ID = SLD.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Server AS SE ON SLD.ServerID = SE.ID
LEFT JOIN Site AS SI ON SE.ID = SI.ServerID 
LEFT JOIN SiteUsers AS SU ON SI.ID = SU.SiteID
LEFT JOIN SiteLicenseDetails AS SILD ON SI.ID = SILD.ID
GROUP BY C.ID
,C.Name
,C.Email
```